# AWS hosted .Net Core 2.0 website won't start when using anything but default app.UseStaticFiles()

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

So I've been trying to serve images from my Uploads directory from the root level of my AWS hosting using the below static files config in my .Net Core 2.1 app. It works locally but when I deploy to AWS it won't even start the application with the error below.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Uploads")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/Uploads")
        });
```

The AWS error is just the critical crash on startup below:

An error occurred while starting the application.

.NET Core 4.6.26814.03 X64 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.1.1-rtm-30846    |    Microsoft Windows 6.1.7601 S    |   Need help?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this it seems that AWS doesn't allow files below the root level of deployed websites. To get around the startup crash I've just settled for the default below despite it being a bit of a security issue.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```